# html5 website with fluid template (typo3)

Tags: html, typo3, fluid

A fluid template is a XML file. How can I use it to produce a valid html5 website?

For example, if I put `<br>` in my template, it is not valid XML, but if I put `<br/>`, it is not html5. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know `<br />` is valid HTML5.

> "HTML5 defines an HTML syntax that is compatible with HTML4 and XHTML1" ( [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/) )

Comment: Well, you're right. But wouldn't be better to use `<br>` instead of `<br/>`?

Comment: Well, <br /> is valid XML, so IMHO it is better to use that. <br> is just lazy (IMHO).